# Setting up JavaFX in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm trying to use my downloaded javafx SDK but intellij wont allow me to do so[image]

This is what keeps popping out every time I try to set it up

Comment: Maybe you need to select the `bin` directory of the JavaFX SDK.

Comment: doesnt work too sadly

Comment: Maybe because you are setting the home directory for the IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK and not for the JavaFX SDK?

Comment: the problem is i cant select the javafx sdk as the project sdk, because it isnt listed in the options

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't set it as project sdk.

Comment: Add everything under the `lib` directory of the jfx sdk to the dependencies

Comment: Did you already try to follow the official tutorial from jetbrains ?
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-for-javafx-application-development.html
I know this isn't directly a fix but it could help

Comment: The project SDK should be pointing to a JDK, as that contains JavaSE as well all the necessary development tools. JavaFX is a _library_. Check out [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)—specifically the section for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this plugin is dependent on an "IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK".

To enable this, perform the following steps:

1. Go to "Settings" -> Plugins and look in Marketplace (or under installed plugins) for `Plugin DevKit` - install this plugin and restart IntelliJ

[image]

2. Go to "Project Structure", under "Platform Settings" select "SDKs". Here you will see a list with "1.8" or "11", or whatever normal SDKs are installed. You need to install a special SDK - click on the "+", select "IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK", based on your intellij install path, click OK, then OK, then OK.

[image]

Now, you should have the "IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK" installed. Try again to install and run your JavaFX plugin.

Good luck.